# Conditional Formatting - Highlight (MIN(A1,A2), MIN(A4,A5)..... loop

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I have data:

```
       A
1  103
2  114
3
4  123
5  321
6
7  243
8  111
```

and I would like conditional formatting to highlight the lower number, i.e. highlight `A1`, `A4`, `A8`.

The problem seems to be my ability to create a condition in which the lower number of the cell is true.

`=A1>A2` and all combinations of `$A1>$A2` `A$1>A$2` don't work. I also tried MIN: `MIN(A1,A2)` with no luck.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you make the two numbers go across?  pair 1 and 2 into A1, A2.  pair 4 and 5 into B1, B2, and 7 and 8 into C1 C2.  Then you should be able to apply the formula across the pairs and columns, if that makes sense, like min(a1,a2) and that result goes into A3 or something.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a recent version of Excel, please select ColumnA HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=OR(AND(A1<>"",A2<>"",A1<A2),AND(A1<>"",A1048576<>"",A1048576>A1))
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select your choice of formatting, OK, OK.

[image: SO33459133 example]

Comment: Tried with no success (tried as the line reads and as I thought the line should've read). Also the "Stop when true" checked and unchecked. My workaround so far is to select just the odd cells and ...formula is true:... A1<A2  then vice versa for the evens. Not the best way to do it but it is working. Thank you for your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use: (worked for me)

```
=AND(A1=MIN(A1048576,A1,A2),A1<>"")
```

MAX/MIN ignores empty Cells
Having 3 empty cells in a row still triggers the condition

**Odd:**

```
=AND(A1=MIN(A1048576:A2),A1<>"")
```

works for all cells except A1 and A1048576

Comment: @pnuts huh... there is nothing about equal/odd numbers... the **Odd** just marks a funny fact / bug :)